# How to drag gameObject using touch(unity2d)

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, touch, 2d, drag

I searched this on the internet but I still haven't found the answer I wanted.

So, I have a 2d tiled game and each tiles position is a multiple of 1.25 for example 7.5, 3.75. There is going to be a player walking on top it and i want to control the player by dragging it and if you release the touch it would be perfectly on a tile instead of in between the tiles. Right now, I can't even figure out how to drag the gameObject with touch. Can anyone help me and explain to me how to do that?

Comment: i don't want the code i just want someone to explain to me how should it work and the logic and how structure of the code should be @FunctionR

Comment: If that is the case, then look at my answer. That is how I do it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a collider on every object you plan to move. Then create a class whose sole purpose is to fire a [**Raycast**](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html). Detect when a touch happens. Then fire the Raycast.

```
RaycastHit hit;
if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100))
    Debug.DrawLine(ray.origin, hit.point);
```

You will notice that you have what you `hit`; with that you can send a message to that particular object.

```
hit.collider.SendMessage("move");
```

Inside the object that you hit, you now have to use the coordinates of the touch position to update the `transform.position`.